# Average, max, and min program in C

Tags: c, while-loop

So I'm coding in C, and I need to come up with code that will take n numbers from the user, and find their minimum, maximum, average, and sum of squares for for their values. So far I have the average and sum of squares portion, but the minimum and maximum is biting me.

Keep in mind I'm at a very rudimentary level, and I have not reached arrays yet. All I know are logical operators, functions, loops, and the use of the stdlib.h, math.h, and stdio.h libraries.

This is what I have so far.
The average function gave me a lot of problems when I tried to put float and double during compiling, so multiply it by a 1.0 fixed that. I have everything, just the minimum and maximum. I keep getting the last entry as my maximum, and a 0 for my minimum.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float average;
    int i, n, count=0, sum=0, squaresum=0, num, min, max;


    printf("Please enter the number of numbers you wish to evaluate\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);

    printf("Please enter %d numbers\n",n);

    while(count<n)
    {
        min=0;
        max=0;

            if(num>max)
               max=num;
            if(num<min)
               min=num;

            scanf_s("%d",&num);

        sum = sum+num;
        squaresum = squaresum + (num*num);

        count++;
    }
        average = 1.0*sum/n;

    printf("Your average is %.2f\n",average);
    printf("The sum of your squares is %d\n",squaresum);    



    printf("Your maximum number is %d\n",max);
    printf("Your minimum number is %d\n",min);

return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is not quite right.  Below is the correct implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    float average;
    int n, num, count = 0, sum = 0, squaresum = 0;
    int min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;
    bool gotAnswer = false;

    /* Don't Let User Enter Wrong Input */
    while(!gotAnswer)
    {
        printf("Please enter the number of numbers you wish to evaluate: ");
        if(scanf_s("%d", &n) != 1)
        {
            /* User Entered Wrong Input; Clean Up stdin Stream*/
            while(getchar() != '\n')
            {
                 continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* User Input Was Good */
            gotAnswer = true;
        }
    }

    /* Clear stdin Stream Just In Case */
    while(getchar() != '\n')
        continue;

    while(count < n)
    {
        /* Don't Let User Enter Wrong Input */
        gotAnswer = false;
        printf("Enter number %d: ", count + 1);
        if(scanf_s("%d", &num) != 1)
        {
            /* User Entered Wrong Input; Clean Up stdin Stream */
            while(getchar() != '\n')
                continue;

            /* Let User Try Again */
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            /* User Input Was Correct */
            gotAnswer = true;

            /* Clear stdin Stream Just In Case */
            while(getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
        }

        if(num > max)
            max = num;
        if(num < min)
            min = num;

        sum += num;
        squaresum += num * num;
        count++;
    }

    average = 1.0 * sum / n;

    printf("Your average is %.2f\n", average);
    printf("The sum of your squares is %d\n", squaresum);    
    printf("Your maximum number is %d\n", max);
    printf("Your minimum number is %d\n", min);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I've added error checking and recovery.  Please ask if you have any questions about the logic.

Comment: +1 for checking results of `scanf()` and using `min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN`.

Comment: @chux Only because I knew you'd be making sure I did it right. :-D

Comment: @chux You did get my Christmas wish list!  Thanks Santa Chux!

Answer (score 2):

The way your code is currently written, `min` has to start out at a high value (not 0), or the code won't work.  The best value to choose is the maximum possible value for an `int`.

You should also consider whether or not you want to reset these variable each time through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the first `num` outside the loop and assign that to `max` `min`

```
scanf("%d",&num);
max = min = num;
```

Change your while loop to infinite loop

```
while(1) {...}
```

and now check for the condition that whether your counter `count` is equal to `n` is or not to `break` out from the infinite loop

```
if(count == n)
    break;
```

Full code after modification:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float average;
    int i, n, count=0, sum=0, squaresum=0, num, min, max;

    printf("Please enter the number of numbers you wish to evaluate\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);

   printf("Please enter %d numbers\n",n);

   scanf_s("%d",&num);
   max = min = num;

   while(1)
   {
        if(num>max)
           max=num;
        if(num<min)
           min=num;

     sum = sum+num;
     squaresum = squaresum + (num*num);

     count++;
     if(count == n)
        break;
     scanf_s("%d",&num);

   }
    average = 1.0*sum/n;

printf("Your average is %.2f\n",average);
printf("The sum of your squares is %d\n",squaresum);



printf("Your maximum number is %d\n",max);
printf("Your minimum number is %d\n",min);

return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume your first number in the list as the minimum and maximum.
Compare every next character with the current minimum and the current maximum and update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

your while loop should look like

```
   min=3;
   max=0;
while(count<n)
    { 

     scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num>max)
    max=num;
    if(num<min)
    min=num;

    sum = sum+num;
    squaresum = squaresum + (num*num);

    count++;
}
```

And I agree with **Robert Harvey♦**.. **You must set `min`**

Comment: @RobertHarvey `min` and `max` are out of loop

Answer (score 0):

There're some issues in your code:

1. Where `num` *is read*? You should do it *before* `min` and `max`
2. When *while loop* executes *first time* you should just *assign* `num` to `max` and   `min`.

Something like that:

```
  int min = 0;
  int max = 0;

  // If your compiler supports C99 standard you can put
  // bool first_time = true;
  int first_time = 1;

  while (count < n) {
    printf("Please, enter the next number\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &num); 

    // If your compiler supports C99 you can put it easier:
    // if (first_time) { 
    if (first_time == 1) {
      first_time = 0;
      max = num;
      min = num;
    }
    else {
      if(num > max)
        max = num;

      if(num < min)
        min = num;
    }
  ...
```

Comment: @Ed Heal: boolean (bool) appeared in C99 only; since there's no information in the question which C standard is used, I've put int

Comment: @DimitryBychenko - We are banging into 2014 so one assumes that one has a bit more modern compiler that that!

Comment: @EdHeal Tell all of the people using Microsoft's compiler to switch compilers if they want to learn anything beyond C89! Quickly! :-P

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean, moved giving the values min, max 0 are the start of loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float average;
    int i, n, count=0, sum=0, squaresum=0, num, min, max;

    bool first = true;
    printf("Please enter the number of numbers you wish to evaluate\n");
    scanf_s("%d",&n);

    printf("Please enter %d numbers\n",n);
        min=0;
        max=0;

    while(count<n)
    {
            scanf_s("%d",&num);

        if (first) {
           first = false;
           min = max = num;
        }
            if(num>max)
               max=num;
            if(num<min)
               min=num;


        sum = sum+num;
        squaresum = squaresum + (num*num);

        count++;
    }
        average = 1.0*sum/n;

    printf("Your average is %.2f\n",average);
    printf("The sum of your squares is %d\n",squaresum);    



    printf("Your maximum number is %d\n",max);
    printf("Your minimum number is %d\n",min);

return(0);
}
```

Should also consider to check the return value of scanf

Answer (score 0):

```
int marks , marks_count=0 , max=0 , min=100 , marks_number=1;
float total , avg;

printf("Hit enter to input marks of 10 student.\n\n");
getchar();

do
{
    printf("Input %d Mark : " , marks_number);
    scanf("%d" ,& marks);


    if (marks>max)
    {
        max=marks;
    }

    else if (marks<min)
    {
        min=marks;
    }

    marks_count++;
    marks_number++;

    total=total+marks;
}

while (marks_count<10);
while (marks_number<10);


avg=total/marks_count;

printf("\n\nAverage marks are : %.2f\n" , avg);
printf("Maximum marks are : %d\n" , max);
printf("Minimum marks are : %d\n\n\n" , min);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, it checks if the loop starts for the first time or not. If it runs for the first time it assigns the value of n to the minimum and the maximum variable and after that, it continues. When it runs a second time it checks and finds that the program runs a second time thus it does not initialize the variables with the value of n without comparing.

```
int n, limit, sum = 0, minimum, maximum;
float average;
bool firstTime = "true";

printf("\nEnter Limit: ");
scanf("%d", &limit);

printf("\nEnter %d numbers: \n", limit);
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if (firstTime)
    {
        minimum = n;
        maximum = n;
        firstTime = false;
    }
    if (minimum > n)
    {
        minimum = n;
    }

    if (maximum < n)
    {
        maximum = n;
    }
    sum = sum + n;
}

average = sum / limit;
printf("\nMinimum: %d", minimum);
printf("\nMaximum: %d", maximum);
printf("\nSum: %d", sum);
printf("\nAverage: %.3lf", average);
```