# Calculating the average of user inputs in c

Tags: c, average

disclaimer: I'm new to programming
I'm working on this problem

[image]

so far ive written this which takes user inputs and calculates an average based on them

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    float num[100], sum = 0.0, average;

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d. Enter number: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &num[i]);
        sum += num[i];
    }
 average = sum / n;
printf("Average = %.2f", average);
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like the user to enter -1 to indicate that they are done entering data; I can't figure out how to do that. so if possible can someone explain or give me an idea as to how to do it

Thank you!

Comment: ive tried making the end of the data entry using an if statement idk if thats completely wrong but i want to show that i at least made an attempt at it

Comment: Please post your question as _text_. Also add the code inline with the question.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Average, max, and min program in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769834/average-max-and-min-program-in-c)

Comment: Since in the condition user has to enter integers - no need to read them as %f, use `int num` and `%d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    float num[100], sum = 0.0, average;
    float x = 0.0;

    while(1) {

        printf("%d. Enter number: ", i+1); 
        scanf("%f", &x);

        if(x == -1)
            break;

        num[i] = x;
        sum += num[i];
        i++;

    }

    average = sum / i;

    printf("\n Average = %.2f", average);

    return 0;
}
```

**There is no need for the array num[] if you don't want the data to be used later.**
Hope this will help.!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need the average. No need to store all the entered numbers for that.

You just need the number inputs before the `-1` stored in a variable, say `count` which is incremented upon each iteration of the loop and a variable like `sum` to hold the sum of all numbers entered so far.

In your program, you have not initialised `n` before using it. `n` has only garbage whose value in indeterminate.

You don't even need the `average` variable for that. You can just print out `sum/count` while printing the average.

Do

```
int count=0;
float num, sum = 0;
while(scanf("%f", &num)==1 && num!=-1)
{
    count++;
    sum += num;
}
```

to stop reading at `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare an array to store entered numbers. All you need is to check whether next entered number is equal to -1 and if not then to add it to the sum.

Pay attention to that according to the assignment the user has to enter integer numbers. The average can be calculated as an integer number or as a float number.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    unsigned long long int sum = 0;

    printf("Enter a sequence of positive numbers (-1 - exit): ");

    for (unsigned int num; scanf("%u", &num) == 1 && num != -1; )
    {
        ++n;
        sum += num;
    }

    if (n)
    {
        printf("\nAverage = %llu\n", sum / n);
    }
    else
    {
        puts("You did not eneter a number. Try next time.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a sequence of positive numbers (-1 - exit): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -1

Average = 5
```

If you need to calculate the average as a float number then just declare the variable `sum` as having the type `double` and use the corresponding format specifier in the `printf` statement to output the average.